# How to fix rows order with pheatmap?

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

I have generate a heatmap with pheatmap and for some reasons, I want that the rows appear in a predefined order.

I see in previous posts that the solution is to set the paramater cluster_row to FALSE, and to order the matrix in the order we want, like this in my case:

```
     Otu0085 Otu0086 Otu0087 Otu0088 Otu0091
AB200          0       0       0       0       0
2             91       0       2       1       0
20CF360        0       1       0       1       0
19CF359        0       0       0       2       0
11VP12         0       0       0       0     155
11VP04         4       1       0       0     345
```

However, when I do:

```
pheatmap(shared,cluster_rows  = F)
```

My rows are sorted alphabetically, like this:

10CF278a
11
11AA07
11CF278b
11VP03
11VP04
11VP05
11VP06
11VP08
11VP09

ANy suggestions would be welcome

Thank's by advance

Comment: What version of pheatmap are you using? I cannot reproduce this behavior. This is using `pheatmap_1.0.12`

Comment: Do you have F as a variable? try pheatmap(shared,cluster_rows  = FALSE)